# What do you have to do to get sessions working in MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

What do you have to do to get sessions working in MVC5? In MVC4 I can create a new project and add

```
Session["TEST"] = "worked";
```

to a controller and it works without any issues. If I do that in an MVC5 project it works fine in Visual Studio 2012, but when I deploy it to IIS I get a 
"System.NullReferenceException" exception.

Updated Information:

I have MVC5 running in VS 2012 without issue. I installed all the updates to get that working and have everything working except for sessions. I don't think that MVC5 is the issue, I think it's something about the project template that differs from the MVC4 template.

Here is my controller action that's causing the issue:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template.";
        Session["TEST"] = "worked";
        return View();
    }
```

Potential fix:

Adding **runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"** to my web.config fixes the issue.

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

I can also do the suggested answer here:

[Asp.net MVC error with configured managed modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161351/asp-net-mvc-error-with-configured-managed-modules)

```
<remove name="Session" />
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" preCondition="" />
```

And that fixes my issue as well. Can anyone provide me some further reading on which one is a better solution and why?

Comment: You're probably getting down-voted for not providing enough information. Would you post the context in which your code doesn't work? Where are you using it?

Comment: +1, faced similar issue(MVC5 project doesn't work in vs 2012) but not due to `Session`.

Answer (score 2):

The MVC 5 straight forward is not supported in Visual Studio 2012.

You need to install **[ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012](http://asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/aspnet-and-web-tools-20131-for-visual-studio-2012)** for MVC 5 to work in VS 2012,  it has added support for **ASP.NET MVC 5 and Web API 2 Templates** for vs 2012.

Besides that, I don't think "`Session["TEST"] = "worked";` doesn't work" has to do anything with MVC 5.

If you are upgrading MVC4 app to MVC5 follow:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

Comment: Thanks Pranav, you're right that it's not an MVC5 issue. I did install the updated web tools and MVC5 had been working for me. I updated my question to explain the problem I was having a little better.